# Why is there a different result when running as user1 and su - user1 -c "command"?

Tags: sudo, group, su

When running as **user1** in the same directory (**/home/user1/WWW**)

```
[user1@server1 WWW (master)]# touch c
```

Creates the file c inside the directory.

```
[root@server1 WWW (master) ACCEPTATIE SERVER]# su - user1 -c "touch c"
```

gives the error

> touch: cannot touch `c': Permission denied

Why can this be?

Comment: @Kusalananda yes the directory is owned by `user1:apache`. I would suspect the first case would also fail when that was not true.

Comment: If your remove the `-` from the command and do `su user1 -c ...`?  With `-` you do a full login, and may end up in another directory than the directory you're currently in.

Comment: @steeldriver That's what I thought. But why would `user1` not be able to touch `c` in their home directory.  Is there already a file owned by another user there?

Comment: @steeldriver that is the correct identification of my problem and is solved now. So conclusion for everyone coming here via google: `su - user1 -c` changed the current working directory!

Comment: ... and that file in `user1`'s home directory is owned by another user?

Comment: @Kusalananda your solution also works!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do `su - username` you perform a full login as that user, meaning that you are transferred to the user's home directory.  When executing `touch c` in this way, you therefore try to run that command in the user's home directory.

Instead, drop the `-` from the command line:

```
su user1 -c "touch c"
```

This would execute `touch c` as `user1` in the *current* directory.

---

Speculation:

The original `su -` command failed because there is already a file called `c` in `user1`'s home directory owned by another user.